# What is $|f'(z)|^2?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> The Jacobian of a transformation $u=u(x,y), \ v=v(x,y)$ is equal to
>
> $$D=\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &
>  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &
>  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> Show that if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic then the Jacobian equals
>   $|f'(z)^2|.$

Since a condition for holomorphicity is satisfaction of the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have that

$$D =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2.$$

I want to compare this to $|f'(z)|^2,$ but how do I compute $f'(z)?$ According to $f=u+iv,$ $f$ does not seem to depend on $z$.

Is $z=u+iv?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

By $f=u+iv$ they mean that $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions such that $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$. The $x$ and $y$ are for $z=x+iy$.

Comment: And this is also the context that makes the Cauchy-Riemann equations make any sense in the first place. So the OP has implicitly assumed this when they applied those equations to the determinant.

Comment: Yay! So that deriving $f$ according to $x$ or $y$ gives the same result.

Comment: So $f'(z)=u'(z) + iv'(z) = u'(x+iy) + iv(x+iy).$ So how do I differentiate $u$ and $v$ wrt $z$?

Comment: If $g$ is a holomorphic function, and you see it as $g(z)=g(x+iy)$, then $$g'(z)=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(z)=-i\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}(z).$$

Comment: So I have that $u'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $v'(z)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$ Using the one wrt $x$ I get that 
$$|f'(z)|^2 = \sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2\right)^2}=D.$$


I also verified that the same result is obtained if we use the partial w.r.t $y.$

Comment: @Fabled that's right! Well done!

Comment: You're worthy of my "accepted answer" and upvote.

Comment: Thank you. Glad it helped :)